# Lines drawn with CALayer different width depending on horizontal position

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm drawing a grid of vertical lines onto a UIImage using CALayer

```
let linePath = CGMutablePath()
linePath.addRect(CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: 1.0, height: self.frame.size.height))
let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
lineLayer.path = linePath
lineLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
lineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
```

(this is actually in a loop, with xPos increasing in the loop)... Some of the lines appear noticeably thicker than others. 
Also - when I put the image in a UIScrollView each line flickers - they become noticeably thinner when on certain offsets (the scroll view is scrolling horizontally)

I've tried various combinations of thicker lineWidth and rectangle width - but none seem to help... hard to imagine why these would cause differences depending on the position of the line...

I've also tried adjusting *contentMode* as per [Lines drawn with core graphics that are set to the same width sometimes vary in size when drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539382/lines-drawn-with-core-graphics-that-are-set-to-the-same-width-sometimes-vary-in)

I've also tried ensuring all calculations us CGFloat - as per another SO post (sorry I can't find that again)

Neither helped

SUBQUESTION - is there a way to draw a LINE in CA? - or is the technique of using a thin rectangle that I'm employing the best way to do this?

Comment: Provide the code of the Loop

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be an artefact of the simulator. I've just tried it out on a physical device and it looks fine

Comment: Actually @Yun CHEN - it's a bit more nuanced - I've just tried it out on different simulators - it seems to be a problem on any of the PLUS phones - so it seems to be a screen resolution issue (I notice here: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions that the PLUS phones render at 3x whereas others at 2x. I haven't been able to test this on a physical device as I don't have a PLUS on to work with

Comment: I found that my simulator

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me with a normal UIView. I guess some lines are thinner because of that the fatter lines are drawn more than twice times. Try to check and remove previously added layer before adding new one, and see if it solved problem:

```
let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
//......
lineLayer.name = "VerticalLineLayer"

if let proviousLayerIndex = self.layer.sublayers?.index(where: { (layer) -> Bool in
    return layer.name == "VerticalLineLayer"
}) {
    self.layer.sublayers?.remove(at: proviousLayerIndex)
}
self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
```

Comment: thank you Yun - sorry should have included that loop logic - it's not adding the lines twice. However I've just tried it out on a physical device and it looks fine - so seems to be an artifact of the simulator

Comment: @JonCook, nice finding!